# Trying to Integrate a Differential Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function with $f^{'}(x) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for $x \leq y.$

I am trying to do this: We have $f^{'}(x)  - f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ . Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ we obtain that 
$$ e^{-x}f^{'}(x) - e^{-x} f(x) \geq 0 (*)$$
Since $e^{-x}f^{'}(x) - e^{-x} f(x) = \frac{d}{d x} (e^{-x} f(x))$ we have from $(*)$ that
$$ \frac{d}{d x} (e^{-x} f(x)) \geq 0 .$$
I am trying to integrate such an inequality but I am not getting anywhere. Someone could help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take $f(x)=-e^{x}$.

Comment: Thank you. I will say it to my professor

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)\geq 0$, there is a proof. First, take a definite integral

$$\int_x^y\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}f(x))dx\geq \int_x^y dx$$

Giving us $$e^{-y}f(y)-e^{-x}f(x)\geq y-x$$

Now, $y-x\geq 0$ by definition, so we can replace it with a constant $a$ where $a\geq 0$. Then

$$e^{-y}f(y)-e^{-x}f(x)\geq a$$

and $$a+e^{-x}f(x)\leq e^{-y}f(y)$$

Which we can rewrite as

$$B+Af(x)\leq f(y)$$

where of course

$$B=ae^y,\quad b\geq 0$$

and

$$A=e^{y-x}\geq 1$$
because $y-x\geq 0$.

These two factors mean that

$$f(x)\leq B+Af(x)\leq f(y)$$

and thus

$$f(x)\leq f(y)$$

for $f(x)\geq 0$.

As mentioned above, this cannot be solved for all functions, but I found this solution and thought it might be useful.

Comment: The last step is wrong. In fact the result itself is false.

Comment: How do you know that $A\geq 0$?

Comment: @Jakobian good observations. I've updated my solution to include only $x\geq0$. Hopefully you find no further mistakes.

Comment: Yup, looks ok to me. Maybe except the word 'definition' at the beginning, but that's very minor.